# Change in energy domain walls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I am stuck on a problem that has to do with the Ising model and domain walls. Assume I have just one domain wall so my spins will look like:

$$\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\uparrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,\downarrow\,$$

I know that if all spins are pointing in the same direction my Hamiltonian is $-JN$. Everywhere I look I see that when introducing a wall it costs me $2J$ energy relative to the ground state. I mean I get that the energy is $-JN$ but the new energy with the domain wall is in my opinion $-J(N-1)$, so relative to the ground state it is just $+J$? There is something I am missing here, what is it?!

Answer (score 1):

The Hamiltonian is

$$ H=-J\sum_i s_i s_{i+1}$$

Imagine starting from an all $+$ configuration and flipping all spins right of $s_k$ (including $s_k$)

$$ H=-J(s_1s_2+\dots+s_{k-1} s_k + s_k s_{k+1}+\dots s_{N-1}s_N)$$

All of the terms will keep the same sign, except for $s_{k-1}s_k$, which will go from $+1$ to $-1$, hence while the mismatched link only contributes with an energy $J$, flipping the link actually costs $2J$ because the contribution goes from $-J$ to $J$.

Comment: I dont get it, H = -JN then we flipped a spin and H=-J(N-1) DeltaH = -JN + J + JN = J where is the 2?

Comment: Note that $1-(-1)=2$...

Comment: @kia1996 you flipped a spin, which made a term go from $-J$ to $+J$. Try to compute again the energy with the domain wall.